# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

My answer to [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23188/did-any-poets-or-authors-say-that-youth-came-after-age-before-bob-dylan) question was deleted.

The criticism by the mod is that it "doesn't" answer the question. But given that it disputes the basis on which the question was made, I cannot obviously answer as is.

I want my answer re-instated.

Answer (score 7):

I deleted your answer because it didn't address the question.

The question asks about the history of a phrase - whether or not a specific instance was the first where this phrase appeared. Your answer posted an interpretation of the phrase, challenging the OP's understanding of it.

While such a frame challenge answer would be perfectly fine on an interpretation question - provided that the answer includes backup and support for its conclusion, and isn't a bare assertion - this specific question is not an interpretation question. Understanding the meaning of the quote is, in this case, irrelevant; we're not trying to understand it, we're trying to learn the history of it.

Since your answer did not address the history of the phrase, it did not provide an answer to the question and was therefore deleted.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with challenging someones understanding of a lyric, poetry or prose. This happens all the time in criticism.

Comment: No. Understanding the meaning of it is crucial. One can only think about its "influence" post that - **not** its "history" as you put it.

Comment: If you would like to discuss the meaning of the phrase, feel free to ask a new question about it tagged [meaning].